# SQL Server : create table using variables

Tags: sql-server

When trying to execute the following, I get the errors

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I don't understand how the syntax is wrong

```
DECLARE @table nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @table = 'FooTable';

SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[' + @table + '](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AddedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AddedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @table + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + @table + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_' + @table + '_AddedBy]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [AddedBy]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + @table + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_' + @table + '_AddedDate]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [AddedDate]
GO';

exec (@sql)
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: remove all `GO` from your script and run it

Comment: GO is just understood by the client tools as a batch delimiter not SQL Server itself.

Comment: Is there a way i cant prompt for this value?

SET @table = 'FooTable';

Comment: Unfortunately - no. TSQL can't do that. There could be a hack using osql, but I've never done anything like that. SSMS templating is closest you can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server is not happy about sending batches in a dynamic context using `exec()`. So forget about `GO`. Just slice up your query where `GO` should be and `exec()` slices one by one:

```
DECLARE @table nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @table = 'FooTable';

SET @sql = N'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[' + @table + '](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AddedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AddedDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @table + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]'
exec (@sql)

SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + @table + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_' + @table + '_AddedBy]  DEFAULT ((-1)) FOR [AddedBy]'
exec (@sql)

SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[' + @table + '] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_' + @table + '_AddedDate]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [AddedDate]'
exec (@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax would be fine if you executed the code inside the management tool which understands the `GO` command as a batch separator (just like the `isql` and `osql` tools). When you execute the code using `exec()` the `GO` command is not understood, which is why you get the error.

The solution is to either remove the `GO` statements (or replace them with `;` which ends a statement), and it will execute fine, or inline the constraints and skip the alter table statements altogether (which looks cleaner in my opinion):

```
SET @sql = 
N'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[' + @table + '](
    [id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AddedBy] int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_' + @table + '_AddedBy]  DEFAULT ((-1)),
    [AddedDate] datetime2(7) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_' + @table + '_AddedDate]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) ,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_' + @table + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [id] ASC ) 
       WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
       ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
';
```

Also, there is really no need to use quoted identifiers with the types (or even the column names), so you might as well remove the brackets `[]`.